# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Function is not implemented."

Tags: c#, ado.net, dbf, foxpro

В целях автоматизации работы сотрудников, была поставлена задача интеграции записи клиентов в автоматическом режиме. Клиентская база ведется в программе с БД foxpro (dbf).
Пытаюсь сделать вручную тестовую запись в БД, но при добавлении значений в одно из полей появляется ошибка :

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Function is not implemented."
```

Создаю объект класса для работы с БД:

```
WDBF db = new WDBF();

        db.CreateOleDbCommand("INSERT INTO CLNDATES (" +
            "CLIENT_CODE, " +
            "LAST_NAME, " +
            "FIRST_NAME, " +
            "FAMILY, " +
            "HOME_PH_NUMBER," +

            "OFFICE_PH_NUMBER ," +
            "CARD_CODE, " +
            "ADD_DATES ," +                
            "CONTRACT,"+
            "CREDIT," +

            "PROC_T," +
            "PROC_O," +
            "MAIL," +
            "FILE_PHOTO, " +
            "RISK," +

            "WORKPLACE," +
            "KDG," +
            "NATIONALITY," +
            "REGION," +
            "ADDRESS," +

            "MG," +
            "INSURER_CODE," +
            "BONUSTYPE," +
            "DISCOUNTCARD," +
            "BONUSCOMMENT," +

            "DOCTOR," +
            "POST," +
            "POSTDATE," +
            "VILLAGE," +
            "DOGOVOR_FROM," +

            "PASSPORT," +
            "AGENT," +
            "INVALID" +
            "" +
            "" +
            ") " + 

            "VALUES(" +
            "?,?,?,?,?," +
            "?,?,?,?,?," +
            "?,?,?,?,?," +
            "?,?,?,?,?," +
            "?,?,?,?,?," +
            "?,?,?,?,?," +
            "?,?,?" +
            ")");
```

Далее открываю подключение и пытаюсь выполнить команду INSERT

```
 _connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new
                OleDbCommand(queryString, _connection);
            command.Parameters.Add("CLIENT_CODE", OleDbType.Char).Value= 85919607;
            command.Parameters.Add("HOME_PH_NUMBER", OleDbType.Char).Value = 1111;
            command.Parameters.Add("OFFICE_PH_NUMBER", OleDbType.Char).Value = 1111;              
            command.Parameters.Add("FIRST_NAME", OleDbType.Char).Value = "Теыт";
            command.Parameters.Add("FAMILY", OleDbType.Char).Value = "Теыт";
            command.Parameters.Add("LAST_NAME", OleDbType.Char).Value = "Теыт";

            command.Parameters.Add("CARD_CODE", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("ADD_DATES", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("CONTRACT", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("CREDIT", OleDbType.Double).Value = 0;
            command.Parameters.Add("PROC_T", OleDbType.Double).Value = 0;
            command.Parameters.Add("PROC_O", OleDbType.Double).Value = 0;
            command.Parameters.Add("MAIL", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("FILE_PHOTO", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("RISK", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("WORKPLACE", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("KDG", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("NATIONALITY", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("REGION", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("ADDRESS", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("MG", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";

            command.Parameters.Add("INSURER_CODE", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("BONUSTYPE", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("DISCOUNTCARD", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("BONUSCOMMENT", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("DOCTOR", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("POST", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
            command.Parameters.Add("POSTDATE", OleDbType.Date).Value =null;
            command.Parameters.Add("VILLAGE", OleDbType.Date).Value = null;
            command.Parameters.Add("DOGOVOR_FROM", OleDbType.Date).Value = null;
            command.Parameters.Add("PASSPORT", OleDbType.Char).Value = null;
            command.Parameters.Add("AGENT", OleDbType.Char).Value = null;
            command.Parameters.Add("INVALID", OleDbType.Char).Value = null;






            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Ошибка появляется при добавлении

```
command.Parameters.Add("INVALID", OleDbType.Char).Value = null;
```

Если исключить заполнение данного столбца, то ругается на то, что INVALID не может быть пустым:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Field INVALID does not accept null values."
```

Перебирал разные типы данных, но ошибка никуда не девается. В чем может быть проблема?

***UPD:***

```
 command.Parameters.Add("INVALID", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
```

При добавлении пустой строки ошибка остается.

***UPD2:***
Строка подключения.

```
using (StreamReader w = new StreamReader("conf.txt"))
            conf = w.ReadLine();

        _connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=vfpoledb;" + conf + ";Collating Sequence=machine; Exclusive=No";
```

[image: БД через DBF Viewer 2000]

Версию FOXPRO попытаюсь уточнить у разработчиков основного ПО.

***UPD3:***
Попробовал добавить строки в другую таблицу из этого же ПО. Вставляется без замечаний. Внес правки в код, чтобы не перечислять все столбцы, а заполнять только нужные.

```
db.CreateOleDbCommand("INSERT INTO cln_actions (CLIENT_CODE) " + "VALUES(?)");
public void CreateOleDbCommand(string queryString)
    {
        if(_connection != null)
        {
            _connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new
                OleDbCommand(queryString, _connection);
            command.Parameters.Add("[CLIENT_CODE]", OleDbType.Char).Value = "Vasya5";
            new OleDbCommand("set null off", _connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
            int x = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }}
```

Скорее всего ***MSDN.WhiteKnight*** прав, и дело в тригере привязанному к полю ***INVALID***. Но как с этим бороться, пока не понятно.

Comment: Как минимум, для передачи значения NULL в OLEDB нужно использовать DBNull.Value, а не null. Но все равно непонятно, откуда берется "Function is not implemented." Приведите больше деталей: определение таблицы в БД, версию FoxPro, строку соединения.

Comment: Есть ли у таблицы триггеры на INSERT? Если триггер содержит вызов одной из неподдерживаемых функций, причина может быть в этом. Список неподдерживаемых драйвером OLEDB функции есть здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/foxpro/aa975628(v=vs.71)

Comment: Каким образом я могу это выяснить?

Comment: Не знаю. Спросите у тех, кто создавал базу на Fox Pro.